# Modify different range values with string concatenation

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a range where I paste a few values previously typed by the user and in order to properly set an advanced filter, I have to change its values (namely the text that sets up the filter, so that something like `parameter` becomes `<>*parameter*` for all cells in range).

However, when trying to do it directly with `rng.Value = "<>*" & rng.Value & "*"`, VBA runs into `Error 13` (incompatible types).

I have found a workaround by doing

```
For each cel in rng
    cel.Value = "<>*" & cell.Value & "*"
Next cel
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to be done in an alternative way without a loop and using [Range's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) own methods and properties. Note that I'm not trying to set a single value for all cells in range, but rather concatenate each different value with `<>*` at the beginning and `*` at the end.

Comment: You have to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the [`Range.Value` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) and many places elsewhere:

> For ranges whose first area contains more than one cell, **`Value`** returns a **`Variant`** containing a 2-dimensional array of the values in the individual cells of the first range.

You can't concatenate strings and an array. Hence you need to loop.

Note - while you need to loop, it will be faster to loop through the array instead of cell-by-cell.